# Regex not matching like expected

Tags: php, regex

This is an overall simple regex....

```
$text = preg_replace('#<sup>'.$key.'(\D*)(?=</sup>)#s', "<sup>".$val."</sup>\\1", $text);
```

I'm trying to match anything between `<sup>[insert integer]` and `</sup>`, and move anything from inside the `</sup>` that shouldn't be there.  The issue is that it isn't even matching `<sup>122</sup>` when `$key = 122`

Is there anything I'm obviously missing here?

A sample of my data:

```
ParagraphStyletablebullet><t name=Normal>Office &amp; home visits  <i>(includes retail health clinic &amp; online clinic visit )</i></t></p>|$25/visit <sup><br></sup>(<i>deductible waived</i>) <sup>2 aSDF</sup>|30%||||
```

Comment: And where is the `<sup>122</sup>` in your sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how you write this in PHP and I am also not sure what you need :), but this is what I got using "The Regex Coach"

**Regular expression:**

```
(<sup>)(\d*)(.*?)(</sup>)
```

**Sample string:**

```
ParagraphStyletablebullet><t name=Normal>Office &amp; home visits  <i>
(includes retail health clinic &amp; online clinic visit )</i></t>
</p>|$25/visit <sup><br></sup>(<i>deductible 
waived</i>) <sup>2 aSDF</sup>|30%||||
```

**Replacement string:**

```
\1\2\4\3
```

**Replacement result:**

```
ParagraphStyletablebullet><t name=Normal>Office &amp; home visits  <i>
(includes retail health clinic &amp; online clinic visit )</i></t>
</p>|$25/visit <sup></sup><br>(<i>deductible 
waived</i>) <sup>2</sup> aSDF|30%||||
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesen't work because your sample has only `<sup>2 ASD</sup>` in it. Otherwise, the regex should work on your sample.

It could be a problem in that there could be nested `<sup>122 ASD <sup> af </sup> </sup>`.

But thats html parsing or if its just text, maybe thats not a problem. Recursion could be done with a Perl or C# regex engine. If it were me, I would redo the regex to not allow nesting of `<sup>`:

```
$text = preg_replace(
"~<sup>$key((?:(?!\\d|<sup>).)*)</sup>~s",  
"<sup>$val</sup>$1",  $text  );
```

There might be other concerns as well.